# time-zone-valid-p: Is there such a function?

Tags: parse-time

I am trying to debug an invalid timezone `'(nil nil nil)` that is causing `encode-time` to choke on the optional ZONE argument.

**Q**:   Is there a `time-zone-valid-p` function anywhere that I can use to test the ZONE before passing it to `encode-time`?